# how to make canvas outline a transparent png for on hover glow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

Is it possible to give a glow effect to an image automatically, say using canvas?

### **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LAS8L/88/)**

The canvas tag would have to omit the transparent

[image: transparent iphonev]

and make it have an outter glow?

[image: outterglow]

```
<canvas id="canvas" width=960 height=960></canvas>
```

Comment: The naive approach would work, though there may be better ways to skin the cat. **(1)** copy the image to a canvas **(2)** set all pixels with a non-zero alpha value to be the glow-colour. **(3)** Perform alpha-based blurring on the canvas produced in steps 1 & 2. (don't touch the colours, only average the alpha values with the 4 immediate neighbours - up,down,left,right) - repeat as required **(4)** draw the original image back onto the canvas. The blurring step will have increased the number of pixels with the glow colour, while simultaneously fading their alpha value to 0 at the edges.

Comment: Update: it does work, though with a problem. I'd forgotten that the blurring operation would _shrink_ the size of the glow. The method constructs a glowing portion that is smaller than the opaque part of the source image. :(. Source available if helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Make a canvas path glow by applying a series of overlapping shadows with increasing blur**

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Z3Lx2/

[image]

You can change the styling of the glow by varying the number of overlays and the blur size.

Example code for a glow effect:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// glow
var glowColor="blue";

ctx.save();
ctx.strokeStyle = glowColor;
ctx.shadowColor = glowColor;
ctx.shadowOffsetX=300;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ctx.shadowBlur = i * 2;
    ctx.strokeRect(-270, 30, 75, 150);
}
ctx.restore();
```

**To get the outline path of your phone image, you can use the "marching ants" algorithm.**

This algorithm will create a path that outlines an image.

In your case you would define the image as all pixels that are not transparent.

Here's a very good implementation of "marching ants" that is used in the excellent d3 library:

https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/blob/master/geom/contour/contour.js

It's used like this:

DrawImage your phone on the canvas.

```
// draw the image
// (this time to grab the image's pixel data

ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
```

Get the pixel color array from the canvas using ctx.getImageData

```
// grab the image's pixel data

imgData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
data=imgData.data;
```

Define a function that checks the pixel array for non-transparent pixels at any x,y on the canvas.

```
// This is used by the marching ants algorithm
// to determine the outline of the non-transparent
// pixels on the image

var defineNonTransparent=function(x,y){
    var a=data[(y*cw+x)*4+3];
    return(a>20);
}
```

Call the contour function:

```
// call the marching ants algorithm
// to get the outline path of the image
// (outline=outside path of transparent pixels

var points=geom.contour(defineNonTransparent);
```

**Here's an example result:**

- the glow is automatically generated using overlapping shadows
- the outline path of the phone is calculated using the marching ants algorithm

[image]

Comment: Marking this correct and doing this as we speak but would you happen to have a working jsfiddle of it?  just incase I run into any snags.

Comment: Yep, I made the last image with working example code (just to make sure there were no bugs):  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Rk3rF/